How to list and get their data from workflows of an Azure Standard Logic App in PowerShell
I need a powershell script to get the Workflow URL of each workflow in a Azure Standard Logic App. It seems that there is no direct approach to do it using Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, or even the Azure REST API.
For example, the command:
az logicapp show --name $logicAppName1 --resource-group $resourceGroupName --subscription $subscription
provides only general info.

You can fetch the callback URL or workflow url by using the this rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/list-callback-url?view=rest-logic-2016-06-01&tabs=HTTP

You can list all the workflows created in a standard logic app by using below REST API. You need to add a Bearer token while invoking this rest api which should have user_impersonation permission.
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{LogicAppName}/workflows?api-version=2018-11-01

To get the details of a particular workflow, you can use the given Rest API.
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{LogicAppName}/workflows/{workflowName}?api-version=2018-11-01


In order to fetch the workflow url or callback url you can either use Workflows - List Callback Url REST API or the below given PowerShell script which I have referred from here.
$subscription = ‘subscriptionId’
$ResourceGroupName = ‘resourceGroupName’
$LogicAppName = ‘LogicAppName’
$workflowName = ‘workflowName’

$workflowDetails = az rest --method post --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$LogicAppName/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/$workflowName/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2018-11-01

$callbackUrl = ($workflowDetails | ConvertFrom-Json).value
Write-Host "The Workflow URL is: $callbackUrl"



Hello, seems that you have there some kind of REST client for VSCode. Could you please share which one is it?

@StanislavCastek It is called Thunder Client

Based on what I've had already discovered, and matching Ikhtesam, I managed the following:
$workflowUri = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$LogicAppName/workflows/"
$workflows = az resource show --ids $workflowUri | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($workflow in $workflows.value) {
    $workflowName = $workflow.name -replace "$LogicAppName/", ""
    $triggerUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$LogicAppName/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/$workflowName/triggers/$TriggerName/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2018-11-01"
    $response = az rest --method post --uri $triggerUri | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Output $response.value
}


If that’s the case then you should accept their answer. They did all that work to answer your question and should be rewarded.

Tell me about it. I had the answer before creating the question. I have done all the work. He posted his answer before me, just moments after the question was approved.
